# ng-focus and ng-blur not working while ng-click works fine in input element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<input ng-model="t" ng-change="updateV()" ng-blur="blur()" ng-focus="blur()" ng-click="blur()"/>
```

I make a fiddle to this question:http://jsfiddle.net/tjfdfs/6Mqd6/

anyone can help? thx!

Comment: Which version are you using? Try using version 1.2.0

Comment: I read source of todoMVC of angular. he write todoBlur and todoFocus directives manually. So can I conclude this: I still need to write these two directives by myself?

Comment: Not if you 're using version 1.2.0. in which these are already included.

Comment: @CodeHater, thanks, I use 1.1.1 because it's latest version provided by jsfiddle . I will try 1.2.0 and see if it can work.

Comment: You can load the version of your choice using the <script tag in the fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `ng-focus` and `ng-blur` directives are not supported in the current stable branch (1.0.x). The corresponding code has been added to master [just 2 months ago](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1277).

Expect to have them in 1.2.0 branch. Actually, if you're able to work with the products marked as unstable in your application, try 1.2.0rc1 to have them [supported](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/docs/api/ng.directive%3angFocus) already.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with angular 1.07 and as much as I know it does not support ng-blur nor ng-focus at all.
You will have to write them by your self as follows.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['App_ui']);
angular.module("App_ui", []).directive('uiBlur', function () {
  return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('blur', function () {
          scope.$apply(attrs.uiBlur);
      });
   };
 });
```